# Why sensor sampling rate become too low when Android phone is still?

Tags: android, sensors, sampling, rate

I write a simple app to read accelerometer data and I found that sampling rate is too low(even one sample 5 seconds) when I put phone on the table and keep quiet. I set sampling rate as FASTEST it's sampling rate always is high.

I want to know why and how does Android do this? I guess jni or hardware always read data but it discard data when it find there is no change between two sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the [documentation of the sensor listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html#onSensorChanged%28android.hardware.SensorEvent%29) the procedure `onSensorChanged` is called **when the sensor changed**. This means that if you hold the device still the sensor values won't change.

I have to admit that most phones add noise to sensor values and these values are always changing; you should be 'proud' of your phone - it doesn't add a lot of noise.

Comment: @MoreFreeze If you're using Android 2.3+ you can use [NativeActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html). The example is good enough to get you started. This way you will get events as fast as you want.